# Blazor How to use a bind to an array of booleans

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have an array of objects in which there is an `IsChecked` property.
With an array I fill the table, where for the `IsChecked` properties I do @bind to input.

When I try to switch the value, an error flies.
If I immediately change the value `IsChecked = true`, then the check mark is ticked.

```
for(var i = 0; i < firms.Length; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@firms[i].ShortTitle</td>
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ... @bind="@firms[i].IsChecked" />
             ..
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
```

Error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer:
>   Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: Index was outside
>   the bounds of the array.
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at ....<>c__DisplayClass0_1.b__6(Boolean
>   __value)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.b__0(ChangeEventArgs
>   e)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
>   taskToHandle)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost: Error:
>   Unhandled exception in circuit
>   'LzL8iNZr7FmkJFJRS3QTW3QzJwP9R-p3CaclRHcE1_A.'.
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at ...<>c__DisplayClass0_1.b__6(Boolean
>   __value)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.b__0(ChangeEventArgs
>   e)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
>   taskToHandle)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: My money here is on the loop variable being caught in a closure, so once it tries to actually bind, `i == firms.Length`. What happens if you just print `i` to the page on each iteration? Is it `firms.Length`'s value `firms.Length` times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (you do not display all your code ) the 'delegate' EventCallback is executed, but the 'Index was outside the bounds of the array"; This occurs  because the code that accesses the Index value always gets the last Index + 1

To solve this, use a local variable to which you should assigned the value of i, something like this"

```
var local = i;
```

[See my answer here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812427/for-loop-not-returning-expected-value-c-sharp-blazor/54813295#54813295)

Hope this helps...

Comment: It really helped, but I already changed the for loop to foreach

Comment: Yes, this was fixed for foreach() loops, not for for(). The explanation is that the generated code contains a lambda, google "lambda closure".