# Why doesn't the binding work with an array and a for loop in my example (blazor)?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a situation where I have a 0-n fields that may need to be populated. I accomplish that by trying to bind to `List<double>` in a `for` loop as such

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{                    
    <input type="text" @bind="TraineeValues[i]" />              
}
```

The issue is that underlying list values don't seem to be updating.
Fiddle below

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/gfhw59v4

Comment: You should define your loop like this: @for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   var local = i;
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" @bind="@TraineeValues[local]" />

    </div>
}

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813295/6152891

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop not returning expected value - C# - Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812427/for-loop-not-returning-expected-value-c-sharp-blazor)

Comment: Yep, thanks. I don't know how I missed this. Rough day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create another variable inside the loop for getting the correct variable

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{                 
    var ii = i;   
    <input type="text" @bind="TraineeValues[ii]" />              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Your for loop should contain a local variable like this:

 @for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {    
     var localVariable = i;                
     <input type="text" @bind="TraineeValues[localVariable]" />              
  }
```

This is standard C# behavior where your code has access to a variable and not to the value of the variable. You have to define a variable which is local to the for loop; that is, this variable is defined at each iteration of the loop, otherwise it's the same variable across all iterations, and your code is going to use the same value contained in the variable when the loop ends.

[See also this...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813295/6152891)