# How to change a variable declared inside a loop?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Consider the following code :

**In MyPage.razor :**

```html
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        var theBool = false;

        <li>
            <span>For @item, theBool is @theBool</span>

            (<a href="" @onclick="@(e => theBool = !theBool)">Reverse bool for @item</a>)
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    List<string> myList = new() { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", };
}
```

... which produce the following output :
[image: List of items]

I expect that clicking on a link will switch the preceding bool value, so it shows "True" instead of "False". It's not working at all, <s>the variable seems to be changed but</s> the UI (the `<span>`) is not refreshed. What is the good way to implement this in Blazor Webassembly ?

(I hope not to be forced to use the `@code` section : it would be a major code overhead in term of maintainability).

### UPDATE 1

This is what I'm trying to achieve :
A click on a link (which is outside of a component) has to change the parameter of the component (to change the component behavior) :

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        var theBool = false;

        <li>
            <a href="" @onclick="@(e => theBool = !theBool)">Show/Hide details</a>
            <MyCoolComponent DisplayDetails="@theBool"></MyCoolComponent>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: It's a *variable*, not a field. It doesn't exists outside the iteration (not the loop, the iteration). To keep track of that value you can make it a field/property of the items in `myList` and bind to it

Comment: The *theBool* variable only exists during the generating of your page. By the time you click on the element, it does not exist anymore!

Comment: As theBool is captured by the lambda, I expected it still exists after le loop. 
@PanagiotisKanavos : Do you mean that Blazor only subscribe for Ui refresh on fields and not variables ? Do you know where is the documentation about that ? Can can't find any. Thx !

Comment: @JYL why? The lambda itself ceases to exist once it's executed. And even it stayed alive somehow, the *variable* is declared inside the loop so its scope is only the iteration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The scope is inside the loop, but the lifetime can extend beyond the loop.  That's the whole point of closures.  Now that doesn't make it extend to other applications, but it can be, and is, extended beyond the scope of the loop.

Comment: When I said that theBool is expected to be captured by the lambda, I'm following this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813295/218873 (see "localVariable").

Comment: @JYL Yes, but the variable is resolved to its value when the page response is sent to the client.  The variable doesn't persist beyond the lifetime of the server's response rendering time into subsequent page loads or into a client side variable.  The variable lives *until the point at which you write out the HTML*.

Comment: @Servy the question is about Blazor WASM, so it's executed on the client. While `@theBool` is captured in the event handler lambda, `<span>For @item, theBool is @theBool</span>` was rendered when the loop run and won't be re-executed in response to the event. That would require a call to `StateHasChanged` but even that would result in executing the entire loop, including `var theBool = false;`

Comment: @JYL what are you trying to do in the first place? If you want to modify a field locally you can use a component with a boolean field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : that makes sens, thanks ! As you said, the key here is "_that would result in executing the entire loop_". That's what happen when I click the link, I added a `Console.WriteLine` before the `<li>` to prove it. What I'm trying to achieve is to reverse the bool parameter of a component added inside the loop. I'll complete my code sample.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I've updated my question.

Comment: Foreach is doing its thing every time there is a change on the page (some variable is changed) . And you set thebool to false every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As theBool is captured by the lambda, I expected it still exists after le loop.

That is true...

> @PanagiotisKanavos : Do you mean that Blazor only subscribe for Ui refresh on fields and not variables ?

Each time you click on an anchor element, the StateHasChanged method is automatically called by the framework, and the UI is re-rendered, but you can't see it changed, as at the start of the loop you've got `var theBool = false;`
And thus, `<span>For @item, theBool is @theBool</span>` is re-rendered to:

`<span>For item2, theBool is false</span>`

if you've clicked on the second item.

Your code will never work as at each iteration of the loop the local variable theBool is set to false; that is you can't see the changes on the UI...

You can solve it like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
                     
            <li>
                <span>For @item.Name, item.IsSelected is @item.IsSelected</span>

                (<a href="" @onclick="@(e => { item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;  })">Reverse bool for @item.Name</a>)
            </li>
    }
</ul>


@code {
   
    private List<Item> Items = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new Item { Name = $"item{i}" }).ToList();

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Copy and test...

Comment: This answer is useful (please do not remove it) : it explains why the initial code is not working (I didn't know the loop is re-executed each time StateHasChanged is fired) . I just add, for the reader, the doc source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#state-changes-statehaschanged-1 . Thanks @enet !

Comment: "_Each time you click on an anchor element, the StateHasChanged method is automatically called by the framework, and the UI is re-rendered_" ==> that's the point i missed in my first attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean value is getting lost with each iteration. Use a dictionary instead of list to store the values together.

The key is the string and the value is the boolean:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        <li>
            <span>For @item.Key, theBool is @item.Value</span>

            (<a href="" @onclick="@(() => myList[item.Key] = !myList[item.Key])">
                Reverse bool for @item.Key
            </a>)
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    Dictionary<string, bool> myList = new()
    {
        {"item1", false}, 
        {"item2", false}, 
        {"item3", false}, 
        {"item4", false}, 
        {"item5", false}
    };
}
```

When you update the boolean via click, the value will be stored with its key.

Comment: Hi, do you know why `The boolean value is getting lost with each iteration`?