# Add loop in an EditForm

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-editform

I would like to create a form in Blazor with a list of questions, each having two options to choose from. I am already retrieving those from the database and I want to get the user's answers. So the EditForm should bind with an object like this:

```
public class Result {
   [Range(1,2, ErrorMessage = "Choose an answer")]
   public int[] Answers { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor component this is my html:

```
   <EditForm Model=@result OnSubmit=@FormSubmitted>
        @for (var i=0; i< questions.Count; i++) {
            <div>@questions[i].Statement</div>
            <InputRadioGroup TValue=int @bind-Value=result.Answers[i] class="form-control">
                <InputRadio TValue=int Value=1 />@questions[i].Option1
                <InputRadio TValue=int Value=2 />@questions[i].Option2
            </InputRadioGroup>
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </EditForm>
```

This is not working and I'm struggling to find a solution.

How should I properly bind the input and how would I implement the FormSubmitted method?

**Edit:**

Following your suggestions I found a solution and changed the Result class:

```
public class Result {
    public List<Answer> Answers ;
}
```

Also added a local variable for i and bound the radio group to: `@bind-Value=result.Answers[local].Option`

Comment: Either use foreach loop or use a local variable in your loop.

Comment: See this answer, explaining the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813295/6152891

Comment: @enet Thank you for answering, but adding a local variable did not solve the issue. The problem seems to be in the way I'm using the EditForm

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Will you get  any error with your code?When I use `@bind-Value=result.Answers[i]`,I will get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`And in the sample of offficial [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0),it binds a simple type data,rather than an array.

Comment: @YiyiYou I do. Will add an edit with this issue in a minute. Thanks for answering!

Comment: You should take a look at [ask].

Comment: "This is not working" is not a very good question.

Comment: "That gives a null reference exception" lacks many details. Which line?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm sorry, I'll add details. Thanks!

Comment: After `Result result = new Result();` , `result.Answers` is still null.