# Blazor checkbox pass wrong number

Tags: input, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating an application with Blazor where I like to have a checkbox group. I have a list of options to display and I use a simple `for` for it

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Choices?.Count(); i++)
{
        <div class="checkbox-option">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Name" name="Name" value="@(i + 1)"
                   @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckChanged(i, eventArgs.Value); } ">
            <label for="@($"{ElementData.Name}-{i}")">@Choices[i]</label>
        </div>
}

@code {
    void CheckChanged(int index, object checkValue)
    {
        var i = item;
    }
}
```

I expect in the `index` variable to have a different value for each option. I was surprised when I started to debug and the parameter `index` has always the same value and it is the number of `Choices`.

I can't understand where the problem is.

### Update

If I change the code introducing a variable where to store the number `i` it is working as expected

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Choices?.Count(); i++)
{
        var rtn = i;
        <div class="checkbox-option">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Name" name="Name" value="@(i + 1)"
                   @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckChanged(rtn, eventArgs.Value); } ">
            <label for="@($"{ElementData.Name}-{i}")">@Choices[i]</label>
        </div>
}

@code {
    void CheckChanged(int index, object checkValue)
    {
        var i = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a vital piece of knowledge.

Your code produces a `RenderFragment`, it doesn't actually render the component.  Your component just stacks the `RenderFragment` onto the Renderer's queue.  The Renderer services that queue when it gets thread time and updates the UI.

See this answer (and several others) for an explanation - [For loop not returning expected value - C# - Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812427/for-loop-not-returning-expected-value-c-sharp-blazor)

Normal practice is to do what you've done in your second code block, or just use a foreach.