# For Loop with MudSelect outputs all the same

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

So if I run the following code in my Blazor WASM application with MudBlazor.

```cs
<MudSelect T="int?" @bind-Value="_registerProfileViewModel.DayOfBirth" Label="Day:" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    @for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="@day">@day</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

I get a select box with 31 options that are all 32. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**
I can do the following, but I want to make sure I am not doing something incorrectly.

```cs
<MudSelect T="int?" @bind-Value="_registerProfileViewModel.DayOfBirth" Label="Day:" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    @for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
    {
        var number = day;
        <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="@number">@number</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

Comment: [Kristoffer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922747/11779494) and your edit. _This is the way_ . More answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a variable `day` that is later updated (once for each iteration of the loop). To fix this add a local variable inside the loop and use that instead.

```
<MudSelect T="int?" @bind-Value="_registerProfileViewModel.DayOfBirth" Label="Day:" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
@for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
{
    var localDay = day;
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="@localDay">@localDay</MudSelectItem>
}
```